# What changes about a Steam review when the user got it for free?

Tags: steam

When you review a game, Steam gives you this option/checkbox:

[image]

But **what does it change about your review?** Does it change the review's effectiveness on the overall percent?

The only change, I know of, is that people that read your review see that, but I don't deem that information important and don't change my opinion about a game.

Comment: This checkbox was around *long* before the recent change that was made. I'd love to know what effects, if any, it had on a review prior to the change. Note that "reviewer bias" does not count.

Comment: @BoltClock I did not notice that checkbox ever before, so it can't be *that* old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://store.steampowered.com/news/24155/ states:

> As of today, the recent and overall review scores we show at the top
>   of a product page will no longer include reviews written by customers
>   that activated the game through a Steam product key.
>
> Customers that received the game from a source outside of Steam (e.g.
>   via a giveaway site, purchased from another digital or retail store,
>   or received for testing purposes from the developer) will still be
>   able to write a review of the game on Steam to share their experience.
>   These reviews will still be visible on the store page, but they will
>   no longer contribute to the score.